# How to initialize textarea content with some text

Tags: javascript, ruby

Writing an HTTP server in Ruby, I need to edit a file in the browser which uses certain source code (HTML, JavaScript and Ruby). I need to put any text file content in the value of a textarea:

```
"<textarea>__CONTENT__</textarea>".gsub('__CONTENT__',File.read(filename))
```

However, this doesn't work if the files contain some special sub-trings, such as `</textarea>`. So I tried to 'prepare' the data, by doing certain replacements in the file content. However, there is an issue if the file contains source code with HTML/Ruby content, and especially if I try to send the source of my HTTP server. This chain of replacements seem good:

```
File.read(__FILE__).gsub(/&/,"&amp;").gsub('<',"&"+"lt;").gsub('>',"&"+"gt;")
```

However, this is not good enough. There is an issue (in the web browser) when the file contains `\'`! Is there a useful technique to place any text in the textarea (server side and/or browser side)?

Comment: you can set the value of a textarea object to anything in js, but you can't hard-code "</textarea>" into the html.

Comment: can you inject it in escaped and then use JS to unescape it on-page?

Comment: You need to clarify your question - you are presumably using JavaScript on the frontend (web browser) and Ruby on the backend (Rails?) but it is unclear how this matters to your question.

Answer (score 1):

[CGI::escapeHTML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-escapeHTML) will "prepare" strings to be HTML-safe.

```
# require 'cgi'
CGI::escapeHTML(File.read(__FILE__))
```

Comment: This is good, but double backslash is replaced by simple backslash : see diff at https://gist.github.com/raubarede/8547020

Comment: If the result is sent as a Javascript string (that is, to be parsed by Javascript as opposed to pure HTML source), then yes, when Javascript parses the string it'll unescape backslashes. In this case you should also replace backslashes with double backslashes before sending the string.

Answer (score 0):

this form is good: 
CGI::escapeHTML(File.read(**FILE**))

except for the backslash character : double backslash become simple.

I found that :
Server side, replace backslash with &99992;

```
CGI::escapeHTML(File.read(@uri).gsub('\\','&9999'+'2222;'))
```

Browser side, replace in textarea "&99992222;" by backslash character :

```
var node=document.getElementById('textarea_1');
node.value=node.value.replace(/\&9{4,4}2{4,4};/g,String.fromCharCode(92));
```

Hopping that there is no sources with &99992222;   !